# signalr self-host and static file server (e.g. owin.selfhost)

Tags: signalr, owin

I have been "too" succesfully with my stand-alone Singular web service. We would like to now remove the IIS server, which does little other than serve about 10 JS/HTML/CSS files. Node.JS has a static-files plugin,

I looked and I saw that Katana, OWIN.SelfHost also has such a feature.
http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2014/02/10/building-a-simple-file-server-with-owin-and-katana.aspx

---

**Update**

It was suggested to use the OWIN.Self-Host which has a feature, but I am unsure of where to put it in my existing code, and if it would effect the existing SIGNALR code (all Hubs share the same HTTP request calls, so I am also squeezing in Self-host on the same port, I wonder if that works). As well as it would be nice to use Scott Allen's ([above referenced](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2014/02/10/building-a-simple-file-server-with-owin-and-katana.aspx)) example which also allows File Browsing.

Here is the code I current use to start up SIGNALR (V2.2) , which is run at the directly from the Main.cs file:

```
class Comm
{
    public string url = "http://localhost:7700";
    // string url = "http://*:7700"; // Requires admin privileges
    public void start()
    {
        Task t = Task.Run(() =>
        {
            WebApp.Start<Startup>(url);
            this.Clients = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<GatewayHub>().Clients;
            Console.WriteLine("Server running on {0}", url);
            Thread.Sleep(Timeout.Infinite);
        });
    }
    public void send()
    {
        Clients.All.display("broadcast sent...");
    }
    private IHubConnectionContext<dynamic> Clients
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        var hubConfiguration = new HubConfiguration();
        hubConfiguration.EnableDetailedErrors = (Tools.LogLevel >= 12);
        hubConfiguration.EnableJavaScriptProxies = true;
        app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
        app.MapSignalR("/signalr", hubConfiguration);
    }
}
```

Comment: app.UseStaticFiles();

Comment: http://katanaproject.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/Microsoft.Owin.StaticFiles/StaticFileExtensions.cs

Comment: Good thinking @Tratcher  , (inside joke in German). I updated my question with what my concern with just ading app.UseStaticFiles()

Comment: Static files shouldn't interfere with SignalR because if it can't find a given request path it will pass through to the next component. Directory browsing could cause more issues because it has shorter paths to match against and is more likely to conflict.  SignalR tries to avoid this by adding that `/signalr` to their paths, so as long as you don't have directories named signalr you should be ok.

Comment: Adding directory browsing interfered with Singular, since the request to open http://localhost:7700/ was returning a directory, not the Singular server. If you have a solution that only has browsing for a sub-directory or a different folder from the executable, and write it up as an answer, I will give you credit for this problem.

Comment: Here is the error I get if I turn on directory browsing in addition to app.UseStaticFiles(); GET http://localhost:7700/signalr/hubs? 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Here's a sample that shows how to reconfigure the location or url being browsed: http://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Samples/Katana/StaticFilesSample/Startup.cs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer is really from @Tracther, and I wish he would write it up so that I can credit him. But thanks to his input, here is what works for me. I did not need the commented lines. All I needed was to set the paths for /signlar and for the static FileSystem

```
}
class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        var hubConfiguration = new HubConfiguration();
        hubConfiguration.EnableDetailedErrors = (Tools.DebugLevel > 12);
        hubConfiguration.EnableJavaScriptProxies = true;
        app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
        //app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseFileServer(new FileServerOptions()
        {
            //RequestPath = new PathString("/Scopes"),
            EnableDirectoryBrowsing = true,
            FileSystem = new PhysicalFileSystem(@".\Scopes"),
        });
        app.MapSignalR("/signalr", hubConfiguration);
    }
}
```